# How to add numeric value to variable each month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, auto-update

I have an instance variable `@balance = 300` that I would like to automatically add 300 to its value each month (or 30 days). How would I go about doing this in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest storing it somewhere in the database, using a gem like

[sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

[Railscast for it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq)

or

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs

Any of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scheduler, sidekiq or cron job, if you are using heroku then there is an easy scheduler call heroku scheduler.

Just make a rake task with code like this:

```
if Time.now.day == 1 
  @balance += 300
end
```

And set the scheduler to use this task everyday. If you are not using heroku, then you will have to implement a cron job.